# Binding foreground color of control to mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control for which I have to change color, based on mouse hover, click or none. Following MVVM. This is the code I have:

**User control in XAML**

```
<userControls:NC DataContext="{Binding NCVM}" >
 
</userControls:NC>
```

**User Control View Model**

```
public class NCVM : ObservableObject
{

    public NCVM()
    {

    }

    private NCState _currentState = NCState.InActive;
    public NCState CurrentState
    {
        get => _currentState;
        set
        {
            _currentState = value;

            switch (_currentState)
            {
                case NCState.InActive:
                    ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGray;
                    IsActive = false;
                    break;
                case NCState.Active:
                    ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
                    IsActive = true;
                    break;
                case NCState.Hovered:
                    ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
                    IsActive = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGray;
                    IsActive = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => _isActive;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isActive, value);
    }

    private System.Windows.Media.Brush _foregroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGray;

    public System.Windows.Media.Brush ForegroundColor
    {
        get => _foregroundColor;
        set => SetProperty(ref _foregroundColor, value);
    }


}
```

**Main Window View Model**

```
public class MWVM : BVM
{
    #region Private Variables
    private NCVM _NCVM = new();
    #endregion

    public MWVM()
    {
        NCVM.CurrentState = NCState.Active;
    }

    #region Public Properties
    public NCVM NCVM
    {
        get => _NCVM;
        set => SetProperty(ref _NCVM, value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Right now, it's getting preset as active for checking. Now, I have to make it manual so it changes on hover, but not getting how to do with binding.

Comment: Using MVVM pattern to handle styling is not the recommended way. XAML have enough capability to do it by itself. Does this answer your question? [wpf c# Change mouse hover background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128846/wpf-c-sharp-change-mouse-hover-background)

Comment: Applying a color for state in the UI is usually not related to a view model. What are the `CurrentState` and `IsActive` properties meant for? What should the `UserControl`  do with them? Where is `CurrentState` set? Should the `UserControl` set `CurrentState` and `IsActive`? Is there a **need** for the brushes to be in the view model instead of in the `UserControl` itself?

Comment: @Orace I tried <Style.Triggers> as per the answer you shared. It's not working inside user control, saying "a value of type Setter cannot be added to  a collection or dictionary of type TriggerCollection". Have used triggers seperately before, they work, dont know why not here.

Comment: @thatguy I didn't write this base code, but have to make changes. CurrentState is for tracking the state(hover, inactive, etc.). User control (basically a button)'s appearance will be changed based on hover or not. There are several button, so to track, there are these properties, to track and change style accordingly. For the brushes, no, I can keep them in user control also.

Comment: @tcmsh, that's because you put the setter beside the trigger, not inside ‍♂️

Comment: @orace oh I didn't do it that way lol. Here ```<userControls:NC DataContext="{Binding NCVM}" >   <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Setter  ........
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
</userControls:NC>```

Comment: @tcmsh Are these properties used anywhere else, expept for the UI, e.g. are they used in the application logic?

Comment: @thatguy No, just for this UI, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVVM pattern is about separating the user interface (view) from the data and application logic itself. Your example violates MVVM in that it stores the brushes and the visual states in a view model. The view model should only expose data and commands to be bound, but not user interface elements and it must not contain logic to that relates to the user interface just like managing visual states or appearance. It is too often misunderstood as *creating a view model and just putting everything there*.

In your case, I think that you can solve your issue by moving everything into a style. The following XAML should show your `userControls:NC`. There are triggers for different states like *Disabled*, *Hover* / *Mouse Over*. Please note that you need to set a `Background`, otherwise the control does not participate in hit testing and e.g. the `IsMouseOver` property will not be `True` even if you hover over it. For no background use `Transparent` (which is not equal to not setting a value).

```
<UserControl ...>
   <UserControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type userControls:NC}">
         <!-- Background must be set at least to "Transparent" -->
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
         <!-- Default -->
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Hovered -->
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- Disabled -->
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </UserControl.Style>

   <!-- Dummy element for demonstration purposes of foreground -->
   <TextBlock Text="This text shows the foreground"/>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer. I did everything accordingly. Can you tell what is that 'BorderUserControl' in target type, it's not getting identified. I tried changing names but didn't work.

Comment: @tcmsh Sorry, leftover from testing. It should be the type of your `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [EventTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), or Triggers in general to style your control.

*Edit:
A little example, MVVM not considered, just for you to get a glimpse at triggers.

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type local:UserControl1}}"
             Height="200" Width="400">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMyPropSet}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Turquoise"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
    <GroupBox Header="I am your usercontrol">
        <Button Width="100" Height="35" Content="Toggle Property" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

and code-behind:

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsMyPropSet { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMyPropSet = !IsMyPropSet;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsMyPropSet));
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I will try this. But I have to do this from the view model file. Is it possible do it from there? In the meanwhile I am trying the triggers approach.

Comment: I just edited my answer to give you a little example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Should I define this new styling in usercontrol file, or the XAML where I am using it.

Comment: You even could put the style in a ResourceDictionary to be able to use it with multiple usercontrols. If this is the only usercontrol where you want to use this style, you can leave it in the usercontrol file